# What is the script that runs AskUbuntu questions, answers, rating, tagging, and search? 

Tags: discussion

This is a question about this website. What is the script that runs AskUbuntu questions, answers, rating, tagging, and search? Is it custom programmed or derived from an open source? It must be on of the best I have ever run across! :) Brendon

Answer (score 8):

Proprietary, closed source and runs on ASP.NET and Windows Server. Not exactly the most Ubuntu-thing in the world but it's just a platform. It's from the same people that started the programmer-support site [StackOverflow.com](http://StackOverflow.com).

The real jewels here are our users.

Answer (score 7):

Ask Ubuntu runs on the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) software. It's a bunch of proprietary software to run many Question and Answer sites, beginning with [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Users can create new sites at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

You can't get the software for yourself. But there are similar implementations, such as

- http://shapado.com/

Which is, at least in the way it looks, *very* similar to the Stack Exchange software.

See also:

- [Stack Exchange’s Architecture in Bullet Points](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/)

Comment: http://www.osqa.net/ is also a pretty good option.

Comment: Emerson is right - OSQA is the best SE-clone at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It's closed-source. The company behind is is StackExchange, see the bottom of this page.

The software runs on a MS server.

The idea is not unique though, there are other Q&A sites like this one, some of them are open-source, others not. Some even ask for money like experts-exchange.