# Ubuntu ask script?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask Ubuntu Scripts?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1564/ask-ubuntu-scripts)

I was wondering if the askubuntu website script is available for free, I am willing to create a website similar, but for a personal website, I'm wondering if it's offered for free, or if it's made on a CMS or something

Answer (score 1):

*askubuntu* is based on [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/), a free closed source platform available only as a hosted solution, i.e. no in-house use (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/stack-exchange-for-in-house-use)).

So, the answer is no, you cannot use it for your personal website.

Comment: A detailed list of alternatives it found here:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953