# Which forum software does ask ubuntu use?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the script that runs AskUbuntu questions, answers, rating, tagging, and search?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1564/what-is-the-script-that-runs-askubuntu-questions-answers-rating-tagging-and)

There are some great features on this website!

What is the name of this forum software?
Is it free as in freedom software?
Is this website based on Drupal? Which version?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackexchange